# Sails.js and Angular.js project structure and configuration for non-SPA case

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, sails.js

I am starting a side-project based in Sails to try it. Most of the pages are server-side rendered via EJS and don't require javascript on the front-end (my landing page doesn't, my "about" page certainly doesn't etc). However, I have a few pages that have quite a lot client-side functionality and I want to use Angular, because I am mostly familiar with that framework. The routing to these pages is again handled in the server and there's really no meaning in bundling them as a SPA.

So I am trying to wrap my mind around these concerns:

- **Where to place the Angular app's scripts?**

  - Is `/assets/js/dependencies` still the proper place? Wouldn't placing them there make the Grunt task inject them in `layout.ejs` and thus in every page?
- **How to conditionally load the Angular base and it's components (controllers, services, etc)?**

  - Sails uses `views/layout.ejs` as a base layout for loading project-wide styles, templates and scripts. Each page's controller handles injecting the `body` part into this layout according to the view "partial" that has been developed for that page. Is this view "partial" .ejs file the appropriate place to conditionally load the Angular app files in only the pages that require them?
- **How to add min/conctact/uglify of Angular' script sources in Grunt tasking?**

  - All the Angular related files will need to be concatenated, minified/uglified for production. This will need to be a new js concatenated file to be loaded in appropriate pages apart from the "generic" js file that currently Sails tasks create and is loaded in every page. So we're essentially talking about two concatenated js files for the client side. One that is globally loaded, and the Angular one that only the pages that need it load. Which parts of the build/tasking procedure will require modifications? Some examples or resources to check would be highly useful here.

Answer (score 0):

**Where to place the Angular app's scripts?**

> Is /assets/js/dependencies still the proper place?

No, just put your angular.min.js in your dependencies folder, but not your Angular app's script. You need to put all you Angular app in the `assets/js` folder ( or in a sub-folder, but not in dependencies )

To be sure that each file of your app will be loaded in the right order (for example you need to load first the Js file which inject your angular app's dependencies), you can modify the `tasks/pipeline.js` file, and specify the order you want : You need to modify the `jsFilesToInject` array which contains all the Js files to load in the right order.

For example for your project :

```
var jsFilesToInject = [

  // Load sails.io before everything else
  'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',
  // loading angularJS
  'js/dependencies/angular.min.js',
  // all the rest in dependencies
  'js/dependencies/**/*.js',
  // loading first AngularModule definition
  'js/app/app.module.js',
  // all the rest of the angular application
   'js/app/**/*.js'
];
```

For your other question I think you need to look at the `tasks/config/sails-linker.js` file, that inject all the Js scripts in the `<!--SCRIPTS-->` tags in your HTML code.

I hope that it will help you and that I'm not too late !